# How can I get soundtrack information with iMDBpy?

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

I'm use the imdbpy package to retrieve movies info, but I can't seem to get the soundtrack information. I've checked and the movie that I'm using as a test (Toystory) has a soundtrack on the iMDb website, and `soundtrack` is on `ia.get_movie_infoset()`, and I tried to retrieve the info in three different ways:

```
#attempt 1
movie["soundtrack"]

#attempt 2
ia.update(movie,  info=('soundtrack'))
movie["soundtrack"]

#attempt 3
ia.get_movie_soundtrack(movieID)
```

The results were exceptions for the first two and `{'titlesRefs': {}, 'data': {}, 'charactersRefs': {}, 'namesRefs': {}}` for the third one.

Does anyone know how to get the info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bug in the parser prevented it to work correctly.
It's now fixed in the repository; if possibly, give it a try.

This code should work:

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
ts = ia.get_movie('0114709')
ia.update(ts, 'soundtrack')
print ts['soundtrack']
```

Comment: I will give it a try and get back to you :)